# Proving that every planar displacement is a translation or a rotation.

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

This was a worked example in a robotics textbook, the proof involves doing casework. I understood all the cases except the last one which is given as so:

> Under the displacement D, where an arbitrary point taken $A$ is not mapped to itself under the displacement, take another point $B$ such that it is the midpoint of the segment $AA'$ with the image of $B$ under D , labelled B' is not on the line of $ABA'$
>
> **Diagram:**
>
> [image]

Now, I don't understand how they concluded that $B$ and $B'$ lie on a circle which is centered at $A'$ , also what is the idea behind the arc of the circle centered at M which they have drawn here?

---

Reference: Mechanics of Robot Manipulation, Matthew T. Mason,page-16

Comment: I don't think there is enough information given above.

Comment: What do you think I am missing?

Comment: $A'B = A'B'$ and $\angle B, \angle B' = 90^0$. So you can draw a circle centered at $A'$ with radius $A'B$ and it will be tangent to both $MB'$ and $MB$.

Comment: I'm not sure how you concluded that we can draw a circle from the first line

Comment: When you draw two tangents to a circle from an external point, what is the property? It is same here.

Comment: Also for the circle with center at $M$, $MB = MB'$ and again angle B and B' being $90^0$, you can always draw a circle with radius MB with $AA', A'B'$ being tangent lines.

Comment: Ok, so how from the given information can we figure out that $<B = <B' =90$ ? I don't know how they got the construction itself to begin with